# How to reduce memory usage for large matrix calculations?

Tags: python, memory, pytorch

```
A_ = torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(x, x.t()))
```

x is the feature of tens of thousands of nodes, the shape is 700,000*8, 8 is the number of features extracted from each node.
Calculation requires several t of memory. How to reduce memory overhead?

I've tried precision halving and chunked calculations but still can't get down to a low enough level.

Comment: Is the matrix sparse?

Comment: Actually multiplication of matrix `A` of size `m * n` to its transposition `A'`  requires only memory for source matrix and resulting matrix `n * n`.